# Why does the scale_y_continuous() function change my data?

Tags: bar-chart, scale, confidence-interval

I am using ggplot() and stat_summary() to make bar charts with confidence intervals. I want to standardize the y axes but when I use the scale_y_continuous() function, the resulting graphs look completely different.

When I don't try to change the axis, this is what my graph looks like:

[image]

However, when I use the scale_y_continuous function and change the y axis to 0-50 the bars and confidence intervals completely change:

[image]

This is the code I am using:

```
Invasive_cover_plot <- ggplot(TipUp2, aes(x=Microsite, y=Invasive_cover))+
  stat_summary(fun.data='mean_cl_normal', geom='col', fill= c('#999933', '#117733', '#CC6677', '#6699CC'), color='black')+
  stat_summary(fun.data='mean_cl_normal', geom='errorbar',color='black', width=0.1, linewidth=1) +
  theme_classic() + 
  labs(x='Microsite', y='Invasive Percent Cover') + scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,50))
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the code as text (not as an image)? Just copy and paste it from R into the question and add backticks (`). Good luck!